# Combine activity custom animation and scene transition animation

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation, activity-transition

Is it possible to combine `ActivityOptionsCompat.makeCustomAnimation()` and `ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation()` ? I want to acheive the following `Activity` change effect:

1. One view stays on the screen
2. Other views from old activity slide out
3. Views from the new activity fade in

I can use points **1 and 2, 3** separately, is there a way to use them simultaneously maybe using different method or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation() should do all of what you want in L+. In your calling Activity's style add:

```
<item name="android:windowExitTransition">@android:transition/slide_right</item>
```

and in your called Activity's style add:

```
<item name="android:windowEnterTransition">@android:transition/fade</item>
<item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
```

You may want to do this as well:

[How do I prevent the status bar and navigation bar from animating during an activity scene animation transition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26600263/how-do-i-prevent-the-status-bar-and-navigation-bar-from-animating-during-an-acti)