# Exclude Toolbar from Shared Element Transition

Tags: android

I would know how to do this, but I don't know the `Toolbar`'s ID. I'm using the `Toolbar` by default through the `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` theme. Does it have a default ID in the support library, and if so what is it, and if not, is there any other way I can prevent the flicker that occurs during a transition?

Comment: This may be a duplicate of the question here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/26748694/1363438. Please take a look. That should hopefully help.