# Activity enter and exit Animation or Transition?

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, android-5.0-lollipop, android-transitions

The title might appeal to a general question but my issue is more specific.

As luck would have it, I am working on a project that supports only lollipop and next.
There are bunch of API related to Material Design that I never used before and today I am facing one of them: **the new transition system with shared elements**.

But my problem is way simpler. I `need to start an activity that must appear from the bottom, but not completely (50%p) with a fading animation along`.

Coming from a pre-Lollipop experience, I intended to use the `overridePendingTransition` method with the following XML in `res/anim` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true">
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0" android:toAlpha="1"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:duration="1500"/>
    <translate
        android:duration="1500"
        android:fromYDelta="50%p"
        android:toYDelta="0%p"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"/>
</set>
```

But the problem is that the whole screen is animating, which means the status bar and the navigation bar is also animated and **I don't want that at all**.

So I started looking for solutions.

Way before KitKat came out with the first `Scene` and `Transition` APIs I faced a similar problem and I think I found the solution at the time, however for the life of me I can't today: **most findings pointed me to the new transition system.**

So now I have the following XML in `res/transition` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:transitionOrdering="together"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_quad">

    <slide android:slideEdge="bottom" android:duration="1000"/>
    <fade android:fadingMode="fade_in" android:duration="1000"/>

</transitionSet>
```

Following this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26748694/3535408) I managed to prevent the status and navigation bar to animate. However, I can't seem to find a way to tweak the slide transition much like I could with `Animations`.

So my question (finally) is : Is there a way to exclude the status and navigation bar using `overridePendingTransition` ? If yes, how ?? If no ... how can I tweak the slide animation ?

Thanks !