# Android nougat status bar shows white color when launching an activity

Tags: android, shared-element-transition, android-7.0-nougat, android-statusbar, activity-transition

In my android application, I have a MainActivity say M. this activity uses Android's tabLayout widget to initialize four tabs. Each tab corresponds to one Fragment say F1,F2,F3,F4 are four fragments.

From F2 , i am launching an activity say C . But while C is being launched the status bar on my device flickers for a moment. By flickering i mean, originally its dark (black) colors . then it fades a bit to white color and again becomes dark. Now C gets launched . When i try to exit from C, back to F2 (by pressing navigation back button) again same effect is shown, But this time it gets worse . I mean the status bar remains in white color for a bit long . Then it goes back to dark color.

I am observing this issue only on android Nougat. On the previous versions its wokring .

So far i have tried 
[How do I prevent the status bar and navigation bar from animating during an activity scene animation transition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26600263/how-do-i-prevent-the-status-bar-and-navigation-bar-from-animating-during-an-acti)

The above link has two approaches :
Appraoch 1. It did not work for me 
Approach 2. My application crashes , because `findViewById(android.R.id.statusBarBackground);` returns null.

Please suggest how i can solve this problem .

Comment: did u find any solution?

Comment: @AmrutBidri no . I still have not found any solution.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I don't suppose you've had any luck since?!

Answer (score 1):

Add `<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>`
In your activity theme `value-v21/syles.xml`.
Because **android:windowIsTranslucent** will make My phone(Api=19) status bar show white for a moment.And cause the activity translate animator not work.
So your can create value-v21 and add the code in styles.xml.