# findViewById(android.R.id.statusBarBackground) returns null

Tags: android, android-statusbar

I'm trying to get `StatusBarView` (I need it for activity shared element transition animation).

I use the following code in my activity:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
View statusBar = decorView.findViewById(android.R.id.statusBarBackground);
```

But `statusBar` is always `null`. 
I tried this code after `onCreate()` and after `onResume()` - no effect.

What's wrong?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya nop, you can get some views with it, like getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content) that return root view from current activity

Comment: @FarshidABZ ok okay

Comment: You can't get status bar view from android R file.
Why do you want to get it ?

Comment: @FarshidABZ, well, have a look at this question and accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26600263/how-do-i-prevent-the-status-bar-and-navigation-bar-from-animating-during-an-acti

Comment: @T.Vert Wow, I'm going to test it

Comment: I got null too, and I read all comments, som people got null and nobody knows why?:D  and some got a view!!

Answer (score 4):

Snippet for those who just need a clean answer without reading the whole topic linked by T.Vert

```
    final View decor = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decor.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            decor.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            View statusBar = decor.findViewById(android.R.id.statusBarBackground);
            return true;
        }
    });
```