# Why statusBarBackground is always null?

Tags: android

I need a `StatusBar` view to put it as shared element, but statusBar is always null:

```
View statusBarBackground = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.statusBarBackground);
```

How to get `StatusBar` view? Does it matter that the root layout of Activity is `DrawerLayout`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26600263/how-do-i-prevent-the-status-bar-and-navigation-bar-from-animating-during-an-acti

Comment: i saw that answer and its help for blinking statusbar and navigationbar,but shared element steel go on top over statusbar and navigationbar when clicked,so i need put status and navigationbar as shared elements,and i get navigationbar view with no problem,but status bar is always null

Comment: Where from do you execute that code?

Comment: I execute this code in MainActivity onCreate()