# How to lock only the toolbar when the animation activity moves in android?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I want to lock toolbar when activities is changed.
Is it possible using fragment?
or anything way?

I want this process

[image]

Comment: I recommend to use ViewPager to solve this problem. With Viewpager, you can swipe between fragment without any problem.

Comment: yes viewpager with fragments is best choice here

Comment: View pager is apply GestureListener??? i want to using left to right slide when i slide up to down

Comment: Sorry so much, I never use GestureListener. But I think this link can help you.(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures/19506010)

Comment: You want to have a Swipe functionality ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared element transition and add toolbar and statusbar.

```
Transition fade = new Fade();
fade.excludeTarget(android.R.id.statusBarBackground, true);
fade.excludeTarget(android.R.id.navigationBarBackground, true);
getWindow().setExitTransition(fade);
getWindow().setEnterTransition(fade);
```

This transition could also be declared in the activity's theme using XML (i.e. in your own res/transition/window_fade.xml file):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fade xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <targets>
        <target android:excludeId="@android:id/statusBarBackground"/>
        <target android:excludeId="@android:id/navigationBarBackground"/>
    </targets>
</fade>
```

There are other good answers, check here [How do I prevent the status bar and navigation bar from animating during an activity scene animation transition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26600263/how-do-i-prevent-the-status-bar-and-navigation-bar-from-animating-during-an-acti/26748694#26748694)